# How to control Azure VMs using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

Hello I´m trying to automate AZURE VM management like Amazon EC2.
Is there any way to manage AZURE VM from Powershell like Amazon EC2 API ?.
I can´t find API easily documentation or how to do it. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows Azure Management Cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841) lists a number of AzureVM cmdlets.

- Add-AzureDataDisk : Adds a new data disk to a virtual machine object.
- Add-AzureProvisioningConfig : Adds the provisioning configuration to a Windows Azure virtual machine.
- Add-AzureEndpoint : Adds a new endpoint to a Windows Azure virtual machine
- Export-AzureVM : Exports a Windows Azure virtual machine state to a file.

.....and tonnes more

Do these not cover what you need?

Comment: That is what i need :) Thanks. 
I Was looking in spanish version and it isn´t updated.

Comment: Wow - you should report this to MSDN - click the rate this by the title, and then select not helpful. It will then allow you enter some text.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure has a REST-based API for just about everything, including the [management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). Additionally, the API has a corresponding set of [Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlets](http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/documentation) that you can call, which essentially lets you automate your entire deployment via PowerShell.

The most recent version, 2.2.2, has the ability to persist subscription settings, obviating the need for repeating parameters such as subscription ID and certificate thumbprint. Michael Washam, Technical Evangelist, blogged about v2.2.2 [here](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/03/12/windows-azure-powershell-cmdlets-2-2-2-release/).